# Xamarin forms BottomNavigationBarXF displayed on top of page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, toolbar, bottombar

I've started a Xamarin.Forms project. In need to display a TappedBage, but with the tab bar at the bottom of the page on Android and not at the top. The following lib https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF is exactly what i'm looking for.

I've added the reference to my Portable project. I can see the page, but the bar is still displayed at the top of the page.

There is no compilation error, but the behavior is the one of a standard TabbedPage.

Am I missing something?

```
<xf:BottomBarPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp"
         xmlns:xf="clr-namespace:BottomBar.XamarinForms;assembly=BottomBar.XamarinForms"
         x:Class="TestApp.MainPageBottomTab">
<xf:BottomBarPage.Children>
    <local:Page1 />
    <local:Page2 />
    <local:Page3 />
</xf:BottomBarPage.Children>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the dependency "BottomNavigationBar" in my Nugget packages.